# How to add a class in WCF service and use in ASP.NET web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio, wcf

I want to add this class in WCF Service and use in AP.NET web Application.

```
public class Message
    {

        public String sender_Id;
        public String message;
    }
```

I want to call a function from ASP.NET web application which lies in WCF that will return an ArrayList containing objects of above mentioned Message Class.

I have added reference also but it says -

```
Error   1   'object' does not contain a definition for 'sender_Id' and no extension method 'sender_Id' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\abhinav\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\wcf_web_app\wcf_web_app\Default.aspx.cs  42  59  wcf_web_app
```

sender_Id is a data member in class Message.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

           ArrayList messages =  new ArrayList(client.receiveMsg(ReceiverId_R.Text));

           receiveMsg_div.InnerHtml = "";
            foreach(var messg in messages)
            {
                receiveMsg_div.InnerHtml += "<p>" + messg.sender_Id + "send message" + messg.message + "</p>";
            }
        }
```

messg.sender_Id and mssg.message is the problem. It does not recognize what sender_Id and message are ? What could be the problem ?
I have also used SvcUtil.exe and created the file output.config and Service1.cs and have  put it inside ASP.NET Web Application that is using the WCF Service.

Comment: You need to annotate your class with `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes. Refer [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts) for more details.

Comment: [DataContract]
    public class Message
    {
        [DataMember]
        public String sender_Id;
        [DataMember]
        public String message;
    }

Comment: I think the InnerHtml is missing spaces between words. Try adding a space to beginning and end of following : " send message "

Comment: There is some problem, is in this line     ArrayList messages =  new ArrayList(client.receiveMsg(ReceiverId_R.Text));

Comment: @Desperado What happened after you annotate? You just pasted code in comment. I didn't get what you mean to say.

Comment: I mean annotated but its not working . Problem somewhere lies in the return object from service. I am using ArrayList in client. Casting I guess is giving problem.It says -- Error 1 Cannot convert type 'object[]' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList'

Comment: @Desperado - `object[]` is an array of objects, which is not the same type as an `ArrayList`.   Please post the code for `receiveMsg`.